# Using jq to store part of JSON in variable

Tags: json, shell, jq

Hello i have problem with shell and jq.

i have file , lets say text.txt and it contains only JSON, lets say {"rows":[{"example":"20"}]}.
i need to write a script in shell that will read this text file as a first argument and stores the value of "example" from that JSON in variable,
using jq.

this is what i have so far , but it just prints out an empty line:

```
file=$( readlink -f "$1" )
variable="$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example"
echo "$variable"
```

interesting for me is that this code work properly

```
file=$( readlink -f "$1" )
cat "$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example"
```

meaning that it will prints out 20.

Does anybody knows what am i doing wrong.
Thx guys

Comment: `"$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example"` is not the same as `cat "$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example"`... why would you expect anything else?

Comment: @Fredegar - What if the array contains more than one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a jq question, but instead of

```
variable="$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example"
```

I suspect you intended something like this:

```
variable=$(cat "$file" | jq -j ".rows[].example")
```